# Rewrite only the ROOT from a specific subfolder not any directory under the subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite only the *ROOT* of my subfolder, which means:
If I go to: `localhost/a/b/` then this should be redirected to `localhost/a/` but `localhost/a/b/c/` should stay the same. So that only a request to the subfolder **b** directly will be rewritten and nothing under the directory **b**, like **c**.

I already tried a few things like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^b$
RewriteRule ^$ /a [L,R=301]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^/$ /a
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^/a/b/$ /a
```

I can't seem to find the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^a/b/?$ /a [L,NC]
```

This is assuming there is no other .htaccess in your system and this is first rule.

If you want to do this in `a/.htaccess` then:

```
RewriteRule ^b/?$ /a [L,NC]
```

If you want to do this in `a/b/.htaccess` then:

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ /a [L]
```

Comment: Ah, ok. Important is to place the file in the root directory of the server. But why? Why can I just use `RewriteRule ^/a/b/?$$ /a [L,NC]`?

Comment: There cannot be `/` before `a` in ,htaccess. You can keep this in `a/.htaccess` also but then rule would be: `RewriteRule ^b/?$$ /a [L,NC]`

Comment: Great answer! So when I have my `.htaccess` file in **b**, then right thing to do would be `RewriteRule ^/?$ /kits [L,NC]`.

Comment: I have updated answer with all 3 options. I had type of `$$`, should have been `$`

Comment: Thanks! But your third solution is not working for me, however `RewriteRule ^/?$ /kits [L,NC]` is working.